# aws 2 vpc in different zones same region: communication using private IPs

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, region, zone, vpc

I have setup two VPCs in a particular AWS region, however each of these belongs to a different zone. As such i am trying to get the ec2 instance from zone A to communicate with the instance in zone B via the private IPs. Has anybody had any luck doing so.

Currently an elastic IP is attached to the zone A machine which cannot ping the private IP in zone B. When testing within the same zone pinging the private IP was successful. All ports and IPs are open in both VPC security groups.

zone a subnet 10.0.0.0/24
zone b subnet 10.0.1.0/24

routing tables for both VPC allow traffic from 10.0.0.0/16 to local and 0.0.0.0. to igw

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> In order for 2 instances belonging to 2 diff VPCs to communicate you will require an EIP for each instance as traffic will be required to leave 1 VPC and enter the second VPC in order for both instances to communicate.
>   Instances with private IPs only may only communicate with instances inside the same VPC
>
> NAT instances are used for outbound connections primarily.
>
> Meaning the NAT will hold session information regarding an outbound internet access request for example, all responses will come back via the same session to the same client... similar to how an ADSL router
>
> Under the above scenario if you initiate an inbound connection to the NAT's EIP from the Public internet it will drop the packet as it does not understand where to route it to.
>
> To bypass this you would need to set up PAT rules within the IP tables of your NAT device, meaning traffic received on port 11225 will redirect to Private instance 10.X.X.10 port X
>
> If only 2 instances require communication between 2 VPCs the easier solution will be attaching EIPs to both.

From aws forum.

Comment: If this process sounds arcane and annoying, it's because it is. But it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you want to do by default. VPC traffic stays within the VPC. I would recommend you resolve the two VPCs into a single one or setup a VPN between two NAT instances.

Answer (score 0):

I created in each region a debian machine with EIP using openvpn, and so both regions are connected.